# email disappears from Outlook 2019

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2019

I am setting up a new computer with Outlook 2019.
I still have my old computer with Outlook 2007 on it.
When I receive an email it shows up on the new computer with Outlook 2019 until the older computer with the Outlook 2007 receives the email at which time the email disappears from the new Outlook 2019.
Why is this happening and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have the same account configured as IMAP / Exchange on the new system and POP3 on the old one?

Comment: My Outlook 2007 shows POP/SMTP  and my Outlook 2019 shows IMAP/SMTP

Comment: I changed my Outlook 2007 to IMAP and it seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As you discovered, the older Outlook system has the mailbox configured to retrieve mail using POP3.

POP3 is a basic "download and delete" protocol without any feedback to the server – it doesn't support marking mail as read, using folders, etc. It's designed to store all messages on your computer and deletes them from the server.

For multiple clients to synchronize their state, all of them need to be using IMAP.